# Update a obj list in js with a form and show it in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json, list

I have a HTML page with a **form** and a **table**.
In a `js` file I have a list of objects (JSON) and with this list I populate the table when the page loads.

The form should allow me to add an element to the list and then display it as a new row in the table.

This is my js file:

```
var data = [
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
        "job": "CEO",
        "agree": true
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Marie",
        "last_name": "Curie",
        "email": "marie.curie@gmail.com",
        "job": "Researcher",
        "agree": true
    }];
populateTable();
function populateTable() {
    var out = "<table><tr>"
        + "<th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>"
        + "<th>Email</th>"
        + "<th>Job</th><th>Agree</th></tr>";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        out += '<tr><td>' + data[i].first_name + '</td><td>' + data[i].last_name + '</td><td>'
            + data[i].email + '</td><td>' + data[i].job + '</td><td>' + data[i].agree + '</td></tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = out;
};

function collectData(){
    var TestName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var TestSurname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var TestEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var TestJob = document.getElementById("job").value;
    var TestAgree = document.getElementById("agree_terms").value;
    
    //insert this data on JSON file
    var jsonObject = {
        "first_name": TestName, 
        "last_name": TestSurname,
        "email": TestEmail,
        "job": TestJob,
        "agree": TestAgree
    };
    data.push(jsonObject);
}
```

I tried to push the new element on the list but naturally the code reload the function *populateTable()* without considering this new element.

Ho can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add populateTable to the end of the function

```js
var data = [
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
        "job": "CEO",
        "agree": true
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Marie",
        "last_name": "Curie",
        "email": "marie.curie@gmail.com",
        "job": "Researcher",
        "agree": true
    }];
populateTable();
function populateTable() {
    var out = "<table><tr>"
        + "<th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>"
        + "<th>Email</th>"
        + "<th>Job</th><th>Agree</th></tr>";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        out += '<tr><td>' + data[i].first_name + '</td><td>' + data[i].last_name + '</td><td>'
            + data[i].email + '</td><td>' + data[i].job + '</td><td>' + data[i].agree + '</td></tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = out;
};

function collectData(){
    var TestName = "Demo";
    var TestSurname = "Demo";
    var TestEmail = "Demo";
    var TestJob = "Demo";
    var TestAgree = "Demo";
    
    //insert this data on JSON file
    var jsonObject = {
        "first_name": TestName, 
        "last_name": TestSurname,
        "email": TestEmail,
        "job": TestJob,
        "agree": TestAgree
    };
    data.push(jsonObject);
    populateTable();
    console.log("Click");
}
```

```html
<div id="showData">

</div>
<button onclick="collectData()">
Add Demo Data
</button>
```

Comment: It works, thanks!
If I wanted to have the list of objects in an external JSON file and every time I add an element from the form I want it to be saved to this JSON file, how could I do?

Comment: If the file is on the server, one option is to make an AJAX call to an API, to modify the file.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: I've never done this before, but I was thinking of doing it via a python web server (running python -m http.server on terminal). Is it possible?

Comment: Just using that alone will not be possible, you need to run code on the "server side". If you are using python https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application . Set up a "static" part for the json and then a method to modify the file.  If you need help I can send you an example in a .py

Comment: Ok I understand. It was just a curiosity, but thank you!